# Elpy starts Python processes at the root of my git tree, not the module's actual location

Tags: git, elpy

**(I now submitted this as an issue in GitHub: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1249)**

I'm using Emacs 25.3.1, Elpy v20171212.850, and Python 3.6.3 on MacOS 10.13.2 .

I have a project tracked with Git in `~/MyProject`, with the usual git data in `~/MyProject/.git` and `~/MyProject/.gitignore`. I have some Python modules in `~/MyProject/Python`. If, for example, I open one of these modules and, from that buffer, call `elpy-shell-switch-to-shell`, or `elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer`, then Elpy starts a new Python process in `~/MyProject` instead of `~/MyProject/Python`. This odd behaviour has only started occurring recently (might be since the last Elpy upgrade, but not sure - I upgrade fairly frequently).

Interestingly, if I delete the Git data *and* kill/reopen the Python module (simply killing the Python REPL buffer is insufficient), then Elpy behaves properly, starting the Python process in `~/MyProject/Python`.

Any idea how I can debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm posting a slightly modified version of the comment I left on the GitHub issue [Elpy starts Python processes at the root of my git tree, not the module's directory](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1249).)

The solution described in [another answer here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/39232/100)

```
(setq elpy-shell-use-project-root nil)
```

isn't working for me with elpy 1.34. It used to work, but no longer does.

I checked, and the following text appears in customize, in the `elpy-shell-use-project-root` section.

> elpy-shell-use-project-root is a variable defined in ‘elpy-shell.el’.
> Its value is nil Original value was t
>
> This variable is obsolete since 1.32.0; use
> ‘elpy-shell-starting-directory’ instead.

But `elpy-shell-use-project-root` still appears in customize. If it's obsolete (and apparently not working, in any case), it should just be removed.

Anyway, I set `elpy-shell-starting-directory` via customize, and the correct syntax, per customize, is

```
(setq elpy-shell-starting-directory (quote current-directory))
```

which works.

Answer (score 2):

Answered [at github](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1249):

> You can set `elpy-shell-use-project-root` to `nil` to start the shell
>   in the directory of the Python file as before. Alternatively, modify
>   your MyProject/Python directory so that it is detected as a project
>   root; see `elpy-project-root-finder-functions`.

The `elpy-project-root-finder-functions` have the options:

> - Projectile project root
> - Python project (setup.py, setup.cfg)
> - Git repository root (.git)
> - Mercurial project root (.hg)
> - Subversion project root (.svn)